# How to stop xmlslurper to add "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" automatically

Tags: xml-parsing

getting that extra node "" while writing a node in XML with xmlsluper.

Got the thread response to use xmlparser.
But we do have a constraint to use xmlxlurper, how can we fix it (or remove it) with xmlslurper ?

Our groovy code snippet

```
def xmlFromFile = new File(xxx.xml)
def envelopeNode = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parseText(xmlFromFile.getText())
def newNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(SomeStringWithProperXMLChildNode)
envelopeNode.rows.appendNode(newNode)
XmlUtil xmlUtil = new XmlUtil()
xmlUtil.serialize(envelopeNode, new FileWriter(xmlFromFile))
```

How I can remove ""
Or can stop serialize/XmlSlurper from adding that extra encoding info.

XML Snippet :

```
<SomeThing xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/something" name="something">
   <description />
   <columns>
      <column name="name" />
      <column name="Type" />
      <column name="Identifier" />
   </columns>
   <rows>
      <row>
         <cell>111</cell>
         <cell>222</cell>
         <cell>333</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>444</cell>
         <cell>555</cell>
         <cell>666</cell>
      </row>
   </rows>
</SomeThing>
```

Thanks